# What are some flavors that have a strong early presence?

Tags: flavor, smoothie

I've just started using [Soylent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_(drink)) and I'm in the process of making it more palatable.  Most of the flavors I've tried adding help, but they come in as an aftertaste.

What are some flavors I can try that might come in before the Soylent taste?  Or, is there a way to figure out what kinds of flavors generally do?

Comment: Welcome to [se]. What have you tried so far? (Aside: In general, you'll get better reception if you mention things like that). Do you seek sweet, savoury, spicy, ...? Or simply *anything* that will hit your senses first? Entirely non-nutritive? Which Soylent version, and does it have vanilla/vanillin in it already? A big factor in taste is *smell*; you might also consider some highly aromatic additive -- or a clothes-pin to block your nose!

Comment: Personally, I could never get past the texture of the stuff. We tried all sorts of flavor additives, particularly the chocolate/strawberry syrups. As requested above, some background of what you've tried already and what sort of flavors (sweet or savory) you're trying for will be really helpful. I know the newer releases are more phlegm-like and less batter-like but they also don't taste "sweet".

Comment: You might be better off with a shot of something strongly flavored first to confuse your palate, then chug the soylent.

Comment: Capsaicin for kick, chili powder for aftertaste. Maybe a little sage or cumin. IOW you don't *have* to think of it as a 'smoothie'.

Comment: Fresh (ie, not roasted to mellow it any) garlic springs right to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I've never tasted soylent. But note that in order to make a flavor more powerful, you'd want the flavor ingredient in most quantity and a higher concentration. And the easy way to make any flavor "appear first" is to make it touch the tongue first.

Say, if you mix in lemon juice for flavor, consider spreading finely chopped lime zest on top of the glass. And maybe also throw in the drink something that goes with lemon. Perhaps mint leaves?

Now, as you bring the glass to your mouth you'll first smell citrus. next, the sour-bitter-sweet zest will touch your tongue and hopefully be more to your preference of dominance. Later you will encounter the mints, as if you were casually eating a rarely disgusting Ben & Jerry's.

Of course I don't know if Soylent goes with lemon. But either with chocolate, hot spice or tea (can you infuse tea in it? maybe on a very low flame?) I think the general approach is worth trying.

Comment: Never tasted it either ... volatile floral/fruit aromas (citrus oils, fruit esters and alcohols, rosewater/kewra) certainly have an early presence because they go for your nose before you even eat it ... and when i see something mushy and protein-rich, I am tempted to put a tadka on it... and most things are best when there is a certain presence of all the basic tastes in it... so some sweetener, some salt, some umami source, some fat, some acidity...stuff doesnt look like it needs bitterness to me :)

Comment: Or, to burn some karma: If your intention is using it for weight loss or nutritional improvement... I think the "your edible shopping/spending should consist of at least 95% things that one can call an ingredient with a straight face" diet is far more palatable. Worked not only to an improvement, but to a weight-problem-permanently-solved state for me and others. Real shopping bags need leeks, pineapple leaves and baguettes (the baguette is borderline :) sticking out of them :)

Answer (score 1):

## Soylent Spices

My favorite way to spice up my Soylet is with 3 Table Spoons of Durian Powder, and 1 Table Spoon of Tony Chacheres Creole Seasoning.

- [Durian Powder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07KY3YJXS). Durian Powder brings an authentic south-east Asian flavor that will remind of a warm summer day in Laos.
- [Tony Chacheres Creole Seasoning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IXQQXTU) adds a little bit of New Orleans into the mix. You can have too much Laos.

[image]
[image]

Try a cup of Soylent before, and a cup of Soylent after. I'm 100% sure you'll be pleased with the results. It truly is a marked improvement.